# Can anyone check if this phrase sounds natural?

Tags: phrase-meaning

"I don't consider my success a result of entirely my own efforts."

Note: I would like this to mean that I acknowledge others' efforts as well.

Or maybe this is better?:

"I don't consider my success a result of my own efforts only."

Comment: You recognize that your second example is better, have you considered alternative words to use in place of *only*?

Comment: what should i use?

Comment: I thought the question was asking if **I am an esl learner** was grammatical! Can you please create a less ambiguous. title

Comment: Edited! Do you mind answering?